# header() function : a small curiosity

Tags: php, html

As for the PRG model, on my web application I process data on the server and than I do a redirect by using `header('Location: misc/page_done.php&message=1');`

For manage the output, on my page_done.php I've a sort of select case when, due to the `message` variable value (1,2,3, and so on), I'll print the right output message to the user.

This by using GET to pass the variables to the redirected page. Could I pass this variables (in my example, the string `message`) trought POST instead of GET? Yeah, looks stupid, but just for curiosity...

Comment: Incidentally, according to the spec, `Location` should be a full URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Redirects forced in this manner can never result in a POST. Put the variable in a session if you don't want to show it in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no.  Using header Location you can't pass things through post, only get.